# onClickListener not get called second time Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, onclicklistener

I'm doing paypal payment for that i have to run thread in onCreate() method which initializes Button with Paypal image i'm calling one function from it which validates above fields then fires an API, if user oes wrong Toast is appeared that " ... this filed not be blanck." but after this when i correct that field and again click on Btn then it does nothing.

```
Thread libraryInitializationThread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {


                initLibrary();

                // The library is initialised so let's create our CheckoutButton
                // and update the UI.
                if (PayPal.getInstance().isLibraryInitialized()) {

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            /**
                             * Create our CheckoutButton and update the UI.
                             */
                            PayPal pp = PayPal.getInstance();

                            /**
                             * Get the CheckoutButton. There are five
                             * differentsizes. The text on the button can either
                             * be of type TEXT_PAY or TEXT_DONATE.
                             **/
                            launchChainedPaymentBtn = pp.getCheckoutButton(
                                    BuyDeal.this, PayPal.BUTTON_194x37,
                                    CheckoutButton.TEXT_PAY);

                            /**
                             * You'll need to have an OnClickListener for the
                             * CheckoutButton. For this application, MPL_Example
                             * implements OnClickListener and we have the
                             * onClick() method below.
                             **/
                            launchChainedPaymentBtn
                                    .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(View v) {

                                            // dealResponse
                                            getDealResponseLogic();

                                        }
                                    });
                            //
                            BottomBtnsLinearLayout
                                    .addView(launchChainedPaymentBtn);
                            Log.v("Btn added ", "SuccessFully...");
                            Flag = true;
                        }
                    });
                    //
                    //
                    BottomBtnsLinearLayout.addView(launchChainedPaymentBtn);
                    Log.v("Btn added ", "SuccessFully...");
                    // }
                    // });

                    Log.i("Lib. initialized", "now...");

                    /** Calling Thread to add Btn to It! **/
                    AddPayPalBtn.start();

                } else {

                    Log.i("Cannot Initialize Payment Btn",
                            "setAPyment Btn..failed due to Lib. initialization..");
                }

            }

        };
        libraryInitializationThread.start();
```

I called above thread in onCreate() method of my activity.

code for dealResponseLogic() only deals with validation.

initLibrary(); It get PayPal instance make use of internet and then set some fields of that instance.

I know that i can call to that thread from that btn Listener code btn i'm looking for another way.

Please... any help will be appreciated...

Comment: can you please upload the code ?

Comment: Could you post some code? I don't understand what the problem is exactly

Comment: Could you also post the getDealResponseLogic method? What you're saying is that the button launchChainedPaymentBtn's onClickListener is onyl fired once correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's pretty easy. While using paypal you have to create button using paypal, so there  is one method provided by paypal to update that button i.e. updateButton() you just want to call that method.
So, your button works fine everytime you click .

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

**Create** and **Start** the `thread` **inside** the `onClick()` method of the `Button`..

**Eg:**

```
Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_Start);

b.closeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){

           public void run(){

               // DO YOUR LONG TIME TAKING WORK HERE.......

             }


                });

             t.start();
    }
  });
```

Comment: Yaa i did the same, actually  getDealResponseLogic(); this method is only checks that EditText Fields have are valid entry or not, if yes then i call new method() which start thread and fires an API then i'm parsing Json from it and If no then just toast that error and not calling that  method() which fires an api.

Comment: actually i tried by implementing onclickListener in my class and pass it to that buttons onclicklistener and in onClick() call getDealREsponseLogic() but still calling only once, even not in debuging mode.

Comment: @Jay i hope you if you are using some sort of flagging mechanism using boolean, you have set it in a proper way.. please see to it